# Is dimensionality reduction useful for convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, conv-neural-network

I understand that classical dimensionality reduction methods are generally speaking could contribute to (vanilla) neural network. But I'm unsure about the dimred application for the input images for convolutional NNs, because I interpret the convolutional layers themselves before the flattening and dense layers as a kind of dimension reduction.

Is it a correct reasoning or dimred could also contribute to the efficiency of CNNs?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Consider the MNIST task. The digits occupy the center of the image. If you look at the whole data set, you can find that there are some pixels around the periphery of each image which are always white. If you trim each image to exclude these always-white pixels, you've taken a significant step towards reducing how much computational power you need, since all of these pixels are now effectively "skipped over". "Always white" has no useful information for the network, so you're not losing an information, and its inclusion can't possibly help.